# Symfony 4: redirect with post parameters when unsuccessful registration

Tags: php, symfony

I have to maintain one project in `Symfony 4`. Unfortunately I am new to symfony and moreover it seems for me that given project has some mess in it. 
The problem is that after unsuccessful registration form fields are not filled in and become empty.

So

1) I have `AccountrController.php` with two methods
2) I have `registerPage` that simply renders twig template (with form).

```
public function registerPage()
{
    return $this->render("@Frontend/register.html.twig");
}
```

3) I have registerAction. To this action form data are posted.

```
public function registerAction()
{
     ... $this->post["username"] ...
```

4) When register fails for some validation reasons it redirects back to `registerPage` like this:

```
return $this->redirect($this->referer);
```

5) And as a note `formbuilder` is not used here. Form is build in html / twig .

The problem is that when registration fails, error message appears (via `flashbag`), but already filled in fields are empty. Because redirect is `GET` page and `POST` parameters are not passed in. How to fix it better and faster?

Comment: Why don't you use one method to display and to process the form so that you do not need to redirect on failure (and thus allow to access the submitted data when showing the form again)?

Comment: Follow the many examples in the docs and simply don't redirect on errors.

Comment: @xabbuh This is not my code actually, I have to maintain the code written not by me and I have to deal with problems as fast as I can without rewriting everything. Because I do not have time right now to rewrite all the code that is written in the framework I do not work daily with.

Comment: @Cerad if I do not redirect on errors, then I cannot return to the original page (because two different actions are used for some reason - first to display page, second - to deal with post).

Comment: In that rather sad case, the most straight forward approach would be to stash the data in the session as the answer below suggests.  If you are actually using the Symfony framework then perhaps [request forwarding](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html) might help.  But I honestly don't see why you can't just adjust the existing code since you appear to be trying to implement new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [Symfony FormType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) for that purpose. It already handles the things you want to accomplish! But if you still prefer to do all the work by yourself:

There is no POST redirect! You can:

**a)** Redirect with get Parameters (And change your route to GET-Method);

**b)** Save the data in session before redirect and read it afterwards, like:

```
// Save to session before redirect.
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->set('your_data', $_POST);

// Get from session after redirect.
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$data = $session->get('your_data');
```

Anyway, I would not use a different Action for showing the Form on error.
Just use one Controller Action and if there are errors, show them - otherwise submit.
Here is a good example how to handle a form:

[Handling Form Submissions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use form builder.Because it will maintain filled data while form validation occurs. You will get all details from symfony [website](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html):

Comment: This is not an option. Given project already uses non-form-builder approach and I am not the one who has decided it. I need another approach.

Answer (score 0):

From Symfony 4.1 you can use actualy code 307 or 308 to redirect with request
Here is the doc:
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-307-and-308-redirections

Example:

```
return $this->redirectAction('route', array(
    'request' => $request,
), 307);
```